# How does "repeat x = x:repeat x" return a list in Haskell?

Tags: functional-programming, haskell

This is supposed to return an infinite `list` of x's. However a list is created using an element, then the operator **':'** and then a list.

The recursive definition of `repeat' x = x:repeat' x` seems to never get to the point where an actual list is created as it seams to continuously add singular elements (where?), doing something like `x:x:x:x:...`

Comment: By the way, `repeat` could be defined in an imperative language as `def repeat(x) = { let xs = new LinkedListNode(x); xs.next = xs; xs }`, which models the recursion in the data rather than the control flow. Where does that linked list end? Nowhere, never, there is no end node.

Comment: Note that Haskell's equivalent of amon's construction is actually `repeat' x = let xs = x : xs in xs`. The subtle difference is that this implementation creates one self-referential node because the recursion is in the data, whereas the code in the question actually creates a (lazy) infinite list because the recursion is in the function call.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Probably your confusion comes from the fact that you are used to eager evaluation, whereas Haskell uses lazy evaluation.

For example, if you were to use the definition

```
repeat' x = x : repeat' x
```

to evaluate the expression `repeat' 10` eagerly, then you would get

```
repeat' 10                ==>
10 : repeat' 10           ==>
10 : 10 : repeat' 10      ==>
10 : 10 : 10 : repeat' 10 ==>
...
```

and this would loop forever.

With lazy evaluation it is different. If you have the expression `repeat' 10` in a certain context, this is not evaluated until the result of `repeat' 10` is required.

As soon as you take values from the list, the above steps are executed, but only as many of them get executed as requested.

So, in Haskell applying your function to some value does not create an infinite data structure that is completely loaded in memory at some point in time: this is impossible because there is only a finite amount of memory and a computation that terminates can only take a finite amount of time. It rather creates a program from which you can pull any **finite** number of elements, i.e. any finite prefix of the infinite list.

Note that the finite prefix is not represented as a plain list

```
10 : 10 : 10 : []
```

but as a term like

```
10 : 10 : 10 : repeat' 10
```

So, suppose you want to compute with a finite list, e.g. `take 2 [1, 2, 3]`:

```
take 2 (1 : 2 : 3 : []) ==>
1 : take 1 (2 : 3 : []) ==>
1 : 2 : take 0 (3 : []) ==>
1 : 2 : []
```

Now, the same but with your infinite list:

```
take 2 (repeat' 10)           ==> -- repeat' x = x : repeat' x
take 2 (10 : repeat' 10)      ==> -- take n (x : xs) = x : take (n - 1) xs
10 : take 1 (repeat' 10)      ==> -- repeat' x = x : repeat' x
10 : take 1 (10 : repeat' 10) ==> -- take n (x : xs) = x : take (n - 1) xs
10 : 10 : take 0 (repeat' 10) ==> -- take 0 _        = []
10 : 10 : []
```

Comment: Nice explanation, thanks! However in this last example, take 0, will return the [] that we need to actually return the list. If I just execute repeat 3 in GHCi, it knows from the beginning that it's a list. How is this possible?

Comment: `repeat'` will never give you that `[]`, `take` will. Because `take 0 _ = []`. I.e. if you call `take` with the first argument 0, it does not look at the second argument (which contains the nasty infinite stuff) and returns `[]`. And everything is nice again.

Comment: Exactly, so how when executing "repeat 3" for example I get 
"[3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3...". How does the interpreter know in advance to start a list?

Comment: The interpreter does what is shown above: each time it needs a new element it replaces `repeat' 3` with `3 : repeat' 3`. Of course, this only works in a context (like in a call to `take`) where the remaining `repeat' 3` is eventually thrown away.

Comment: I have added, for each evaluation step, the equation being used. You just match and replace subexpressions until you are finished.

Comment: @Michael Why do you think you need to get to the `[]` to "actually return a list"?

Comment: @immibis Because if you open GHCi and write 1:2:3, you will get an error instead of a list. However as Ryan Reich said, in this function's case we define the type with (:) :: a -> [a] -> [a], so it infers that it's a list.

Comment: I would implement `repeat'` as `repeat' x = rx where rx = x : rx`. This turns an infinite data structure into a finite one. Any chance GHC does the same for you? I think it can...

Comment: @Michael try `1:2:3:undefined`. The first three elements of the resulting list are 1, 2 and 3.

Comment: @JanDvorak I don't understand. Your definition of `repeat'` is still infinitely recursive... (unless I'm missing something)  Re: your second comment, I might be splitting hairs, but are you sure `1:2:3:undefined` *is* a list? It types and compiles, but it's neither a finite list (what's the `length` of `1:2:3:undefined`?) nor an infinite list (because you cannot take as many consecutive elements as you want). So *is* it a list at all? :)

Comment: @Andres it is a list, but its length is undefined and trying to access it results in a runtime exception.

Comment: @AndresF: If you type it in the ghci REPL you get: `[1,2,3*** Exception: Prelude.undefined`. But if you type: `take 3 (1 : 2 : 3 : undefined)`, lo and behold, you get `[1,2,3]`! Why? Because the term is evaluated lazily: once `take` has gotten 3 elements out of the term, it does not proceed to evaluate the `undefined` and so no exception is thrown.

Comment: @AndresF: In Haskell, a list is really either the empty list `[]`, or a term of the form `t : ts`. Whether `t` and `ts` evaluate to something meaningful only matters when you want to examine them. Try typing `length (undefined : 1 : [])`, you get 2! Why? Because you do not need to look at the elements of a list in order to find its length, you only need to count how many `:` it contains before reaching `[]` (assuming the list is finite and you do reach a `[]` eventually).

Comment: @andres the difference is that in the definition in answer, when not optimised, results in an unevaluated thunk that evaluates to a list whose tail is a _new_ unevaluated thunk isomorphic to the old one. My suggested implementation evaluates to a list whose tail is the _same_ thunk. You can't tell them apart in code but the latter is slightly faster and uses less memory.

Comment: @Giorgio I'm sure you replied to me by mistake. I understand how both lazy lists and `undefined` work in Haskell :) My point was that said "list" was neither a finite nor an infinite list (because it doesn't have the properties of either), which arguably can be considered as making it "not a list". I'm splitting hairs here.

Comment: @JanDvorak Thanks for the explanation! I wasn't aware of that.

Comment: @Giorgio Note that `(undefined : 1 : [])` and `(1 : 2: undefined)` are different (i.e the first doesn't "break" lists). I was referring to the latter in my comment. By the way, your answer has my +1.

Comment: @AndresF.: In what sense does `(1 : 2: undefined)` "break" lists while `(undefined : 1 : [])` doesn't? Both have `undefined` as argument to the `:` value constructor.

Comment: @AndresF.: "I'm sure you replied to me by mistake.": I have overlooked your other comments and answers about Haskell, so I did not need to give such a detailed explanation. Maybe we can meet in chat some time and discuss what a list actually is? I find the topic interesting. I would prefer to discuss it in chat so we can clean up the comments here.

Comment: @Giorgio Sure! When I have time I'll start a chat with you and we can discuss all about lists :) I find the topic interesting too. I may very well be mistaken about this, anyway.

Comment: @gio be sure to visit the official SO chatroom about Haskell. HTTP://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83002/

Answer (score 7):

You seem to have two confusions here: first, how does Haskell ever complete a recursive definition such as `repeat x = x:repeat x`, and second, how does it know that this does, in fact, define a list.

The first is answered, as the other responses have done, by saying "laziness".  Writing `repeat x = x:repeat x` is actually a description of the value `repeat x`, to be consulted whenever individual entries in that value are needed.

The second is called "type inference" and goes like this.  Haskell knows that the operator `:` has the following type:

```
(:) :: a -> [a] -> [a]
```

and therefore, in an expression `x:y`, y must be a list whose elements have the same type as x, and the expression itself is this kind of list as well.  So in `x:repeat x`, we must have `repeat x` be a list of values with the same type as x, and then the result of this is also such a list.  So it works out, at least for types, to declare that this list should equal `repeat x` itself.

Comment: Spot on, I didn't think of type inference!

Comment: @Michael It's worth remembering that Haskell always knows the type.  That, more than its functional nature, is its distinguishing characteristic.

Answer (score 2):

It creates an *infinite* list.

Since Haskell is lazy, the next invocation of `repeat` is not executed until it is needed for other computation. If you only need the first element of `x:xs`, `x` will be computed but `xs` will not be.

This way you can get as much of your infinite list as you need, beginning from the first element. E.g. `take 5 $ repeat 'A'` will give you `"AAAAA"` without computing the infinite rest of `A`s.

Comment: I get that, but in order to create a simple finite list for example we need to do: 1:2:3:[]. My problem is the final :[]. We actually need to provide that in order to create a list, otherwise 1:2:3 wouldn't work. So my question is, where is that :[] part in this definition? 

Edit: Okay I also get that if we put it in the end it won't be infinite, but I'm just wondering how the interpreter knows it's a list.

Comment: @Michael Been a while since I last used Haskell, but isn't the `:` operator meant to concatenate in list form?

Comment: @Michael The right hand argument to `:` requires a list whose elements have the same type as the left argument. The type of `repeat x` matches this requirement. Honestly "list" is a bit of a misnomer in Haskell, I feel "stream" would be a better name.

Comment: @Doval: In an eager language you can call a lazy list a stream. In Haskell there is no real difference.

Comment: @Giorgio What I'm trying to say is that finite lists and lazy/potentially-infinite lists/streams are two different things, and Haskell's terminology muddies the water needlessly by calling the latter by the name of the former. I'm really just splitting hairs here but sometimes this sort of thing does cause confusion. It's a bit misleading to say there's no real difference in Haskell because Haskell doesn't have a type for "definitely finite" lists.

Comment: @Giorgio: Who calls lazy lists "streams" in eager-by-default languages?  You generally see them called stuff like *iterators*, *generators*, or *enumerators*, but a *stream* is something very different, an abstraction for (more or less) sequential access to IO.

Comment: @MasonWheeler Well, in Scala they are called Streams. I don't know if this is an universally accepted terminology outside Scala, though.

Comment: One can see `xs` in `x:xs` as an instruction how to compute the rest of the elements. The `[]` just says that there's no way to compute more elements, but it's just one way to compute more elements! Since we don't necessarily _perform_ the instruction to compute more elements, we can represent "infinite lists" (or "streams", or "generators") that just won't end.

Comment: @AndresF.: Then what are streams called in Scala? :P

Comment: @MasonWheeler: Scala, SML, Scheme, Lisp, to make a few examples. See also the book SICP which uses scheme but illustrates the concept from an abstract point of view. You can easily implement them in Java, Python, etc using delayed evaluation.

Comment: @MasonWheeler: In Scala they are called streams: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Stream

Comment: @MasonWheeler You mean like `InputStream` et al? Those are from *Java* (though of course they can be used in Scala). In Scala, `Stream`s are unrelated to file I/O and actually refer to lazy lists.

Comment: @MasonWheeler It's not a stretch to think of an IO stream as a lazy list that produces bytes or strings through black magic.

Comment: @Doval It's not a stretch to think of an *input* stream as such, but what about an *output* stream?

Comment: @MasonWheeler An output stream is just the black magic that creates someone else's input stream I guess.

Comment: @MasonWheeler: An output stream is like an input stream, with producer and consumer swapped.

Comment: @AndresF. Yeah, that's my point: it's a bit silly to reuse a word that already has a well-defined meaning on your platform (the JVM, in this case) to have a completely different well-defined meaning.  (On the CLR side, the award should go to "assembly", which has meant *something very different from "library" or "module"* for decades!)

Comment: The word stream has had a well-defined meaning at least since the 1980s (SICP). Also, I do not think that the concept of a stream used for IO is very far from that. Only the way in which you access a stream of data varies. When you are calling `getc()` in C you are actually pulling the next byte from a potentially infinite list / stream.

Comment: @MasonWheeler Silly or not, it's standard practice for many eager-by-default languages, which I guess was Giorgio's original comment... It's even *Java's* accepted terminology, [as of Java 8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html). I guess they "got with the times" ;)

Comment: Note that there are many ways to process streams of data: you can create them lazily (Haskell), you can iterate over them (e.g. in Python), you can use callbacks to be notified when a new value is ready (see http://reactivex.io/intro.html)

Answer (score 0):

Expressed in pseudo-Java 8, this is how `repeat` works under the covers (and Haskell data types in general):

```
/**
 * A "thunk" is a structure that wraps around a Supplier,
 * computes its result when first requested, caches it and 
 * then uses that cached value afterwards.
 *
 * The Haskell runtime generally passes thunks around between
 * object code routines and only computes the thunks's values when
 * they're really needed.  Exception: the compiler may optimize thunks
 * away in cases where it's safe to do so.
 */
abstract class Thunk<A> implements Supplier<A> {
    private Supplier<A> supplier;
    private A value = null;

    synchronized A get() {
        if (value == null) {
            value = supplier.get();
        }
        return value;
    }
}

/**
 * A single-linked list node, but the head and tail are
 * stored as thunks, not as values directly.
 */
class Node<A> {
    final Thunk<A> head;
    final Thunk<Optional<Node<A>>> tail;

    Node(Thunk<A> head, Thunk<Optional<Node<A>>> tail) {
        this.head = head;
        this.tail = tail;
    }
}

/**
 * The repeat function takes a thunk that produces an element value,
 * and gives you back a thunk that, as you chase it down, will gradually
 * produce an infinite list.
 *
 * The runtime structure for a Haskell-style list, in effect, is like 
 * the return type of this function: a `Thunk<Optional<Node<A>>>`.
 */
static <A> Thunk<Optional<Node<A>>> repeat(Thunk<A> elem) {
    return new Thunk<>(() -> Optional.of(new Node<A>(elem, repeat elem)));
}
```

Of course, in Haskell laziness and thunks are implicit, so you just write this:

```
repeat :: a -> [a]
repeat x = x : repeat x
```